# Parse times in Apache log with Perl

Tags: apache, perl, datetime

How to parse dates/times in Apache log with Perl?

Example date/time in Apache log:

[Tue May 20 13:23:17 2014]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is number of seconds since epoch,

```
use Time::Piece;

my $str = "[Tue May 20 13:23:17 2014]";

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($str, "[%a %B %d %H:%M:%S %Y]");
print $t->epoch, "\n";
# print $t, "\n"; check if correctly parsed
```